# Can't open module file 'dflib.mod' error in CodeBlocks

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks 20.03 on Windows in order to compile a population balance solver called SWEEP. The source codes are .f90 files but were written in 2006 and compiled using Compaq Visual Fortran (CVF) 6.6 IDE. I come accross alot of errors when trying to compile since statements were written in an older format. In a certain subroutine of the code, the following statement:

```
Use DFLIB, Only: NARGS, GETARG
```

results in an error:

```
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'dflib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

So it seems that dflib module is not in the CodeBlocks library but I have no idea how to solve this issue as I am new to Fortran and only using it for this specific application (SWEEP). Is there a way to get around this issue and successfully compile the tool in CodeBlocks ?

Comment: `Use DFLIB, Only: NARGS, GETARG` is not an "older format" statement. Instead it relies on a non-standard intrinsic module provided by CVF. You will need to use a compiler which has this intrinsic, provide an alternative implementation of the intrinsic module, or port the code away from this non-standard module.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus for your promt response. Do you by any chance know an open source compiler that has this intrinsic ?

Comment: Guessing from the names `command_argument_count` and `get_command_argument` are the standard, portable replacements - but you will need to do a bit of research to be sure

Comment: A `getarg` non-standard function is commonly supplied by many compilers as an extension, just not in this module. Many however use `iargc` as their non-standard extension, instead of `nargs`, see https://iric-solver-dev-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07/01_loading_args.html **The ultimate solution is to port your code to the real standard Fortran using the procedures `command_argument_count` and `get_command_argument` listed by Ian Bush above.** BTW, Intel Fortran is not open source, but can be obtained free of charge and is a direct successor to Compaq Fortran.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarifications. The problem was solved using the standard replacements as @IanBush suggested.

Comment: Because it was resolved by using these replacements, I linked a question with a respective answer so that it does not remain open and unanswered here.